# How to slide OUT modal without using jQuery?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-animations

Is there a way that I could slide out my modal which slides in?I've written a code that makes the modal slide in from left to right and  I cant figure out how to slide out the modal. Can anyone help me with this? When the user clicks on the x button, the modal should slide out from right to left.

Thanks in advance!!

```css
.headerContactModal {
    background-color: white;
    color: #1a66b1;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.headerContactModalMessage {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.headerContactModalExit{
  z-index: 999;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  color: $dark_gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.headerContactModalPhone {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.slidein {
  animation-duration: 700ms;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left:100%;
  }

  to {
    margin-left:0%;
  }
}
```

```html
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Button from '../../../common_ui/leafs/Button';
import GenericTextField from '../../components/GenericTextField';
import Icon from '../../../common_ui/leafs/Icon';

class HeaderContactModal extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    phoneNumber: PropTypes.string,
    messageText: PropTypes.string
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    phoneNumber: '1-800-CALLUS',
    messageText: 'Call us:'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="headerContactModal slidein">
        <span className="headerContactModalMessage">{this.props.messageText}</span>
        <span className="headerContactModalPhone">{this.props.phoneNumber}</span>
        <span onClick={this.props.contractContactUs}><Icon className="fa-close headerContactModalExit"/></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderContactModal;
```

Comment: Do you know how to set state in react? Just have some modal state like `modalIsOpen: true|false` and have your className depend on it `className={\`headerContactModal ${this.state.modalIsOpen ? 'slidein' : 'slideout'}\`}`

Comment: Yep I know to set state. But how about the animation for slide out?

Comment: just reverse the order of the keyframes?

Comment: `${this.state.modalIsOpen ?` ?? Is that not jQuery?

Comment: no that's string interpolation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).  Simple addon to react to handle transition animations when moving between states (such as open/closed on your modal).